# Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_NDK' for task ':app:cargoBuildDebug' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:cargoBuildDebug'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_NDK' for task ':app:cargoBuildDebug' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Give me early solution as soon as possible

Comment: Did you checked the Check Gradle Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `android>app>build.gradle` file and change `flutter.ndkVersion` to the latest version. Check the latest ndk version [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads)

Comment: already used letest version